# Streaming to website instead of Window OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, web, video-streaming

## Human Recogition Program

class PeopleTracker:

```
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
caps = cv2.VideoCapture(r'C:/Users/Emyr/Documents/Jupyter/pedestrian-detection/video/Ped4.MOV')
count = int(caps.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
center = []
recCount = 0
pick = 0
#          Red       Yellow      Blue      Green     Purple 
colors = [(255,0,0),(255,255,0),(0,0,255),(0,128,0),(128,0,128)]

def BBoxes(self, frame):
    #frame = imutils.resize(frame, width = min(frame.shape[0], frame.shape[1]))
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width= 1000,height = 1000)

    # detect people in the image
    (rects, weights) = self.hog.detectMultiScale(frame, winStride=(1,1), padding=(3, 3), scale=0.5)
    
    # apply non-maxima suppression to the bounding boxes using a
    # fairly large overlap threshold to try to maintain overlapping
    # boxes that are still people
    
    rects = np.array([[x, y, x + w, y + h] for (x, y, w, h) in rects])
    
    self.pick = non_max_suppression(rects, probs=None, overlapThresh=0.7)

    # draw the final bounding boxes
    self.recCount  = 0
    
    for (xA, yA, xB, yB) in self.pick:
      
        #cv2.rectangle(frame, (xA, yA), (xB, yB), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        
        CentxPos = int((xA + xB)/2)
        CentyPos = int((yA + yB)/2)
    
        cv2.circle(frame,(CentxPos, CentyPos), 5, (0,255,0), -1)
        self.recCount += 1
        
        if len(rects) >1:
               self.center.append([CentxPos, CentyPos])
      

    return frame


def Clustering(self, frame):
    
    db = DBSCAN(eps= 70, min_samples = 2).fit(self.center)
    
    labels = db.labels_
    
    # Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
    n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
    n_noise_ = list(labels).count(-1)
    #print("Labels: ", labels)
    # Black removed and is used for noise instead.
    unique_labels = set(labels)
    #print("Unique Labels: ", unique_labels)
    
    #colors = plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 255, len(unique_labels)))

    #colors = [(random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255)) for k in range(len(unique_labels)) ]
    
    #print(self.colors)
    
    i = 0
    
    for (xA, yA, xB, yB) in self.pick:
        
        if labels[i] == -1:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (xA, yA), (xB, yB), (0, 0, 0), 2)
            i += 1
        else:
          
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (xA, yA), (xB, yB), (self.colors[labels[i]][0], self.colors[labels[i]][1], self.colors[labels[i]][2]), 2)
            i += 1
    
    
    #print("Colours: ", colors)
    center = np.asarray(self.center)
    
    #fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        
    #ax.set_xlim(0,frame.shape[1])
    #ax.set_ylim(frame.shape[0], 0)
    
    #for k, col in zip(unique_labels, colors):
        
        #if k == -1:
             #Black used for noise.
             #col = [0, 0, 0, 1]

        #class_member_mask = (labels == k)
        #xy = center[class_member_mask]
        #plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col), markeredgecolor='k', markersize=8)
```

def main():

```
PT = PeopleTracker()
PT.hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())

    

while PT.count > 1:

    PT.center = []

    ret, frame = PT.caps.read()

    frame = PT.BBoxes(frame)

    if PT.recCount >= 2:

        PT.Clustering(frame)
        

        #plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
        #plt.show()   
        cv2.imshow("Tracker", frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        #cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        PT.count = PT.count - 1

    else:
        
        cv2.imshow("Tracker", frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        #cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        PT.count = PT.count - 1
```

[image: screenshot]

The code I currently have here displays the stream of an existing human recognition video to a window (as shown in the picture in the link), if possible I was wondering is there a way in which I can send that video feed to a website that im developing instead of using a window?

Thank You in advance :)

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.learnopencv.com/turn-your-opencv-code-into-a-web-api-in-under-10-minutes-part-1/ ?

Comment: I had a look at that page and unfortunately the information that page provides doesnt have anything to do with what im trying to do, im trying to display video feed produced by the python program in an <img> tag on a webpage, if you have any further suggestions or if im misunderstanding something im open to talk :)

Comment: Yeh, I don't know about you but I'm finding the online tutorials better than the documentation for finding out returns/params etc, the docs are poor (at least for the python version). Trying to do stuff with Kalman and the docs aren't helping at all! :/

Comment: What you are looking for is called HTTP Live Streaming (HLS). Take a look at this link: https://medium.com/@bmabir17/http-live-streaming-hls-server-with-python-part-i-8ccfeb429de7

Comment: Would CGI work?

Comment: But the thing is this program isnt live streaming, its using an existing video and then identifying who human in the picture will live streaming method work with a preexisting video?

Answer (score 0):

I have it semi-working, I ended up using flask but the problem is that im displaying the original video not the one produced by opencv i was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how i could implement the prior code into this? and use the "**frame**" variable for the video feed

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import cv2
import sys
import numpy

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen():
    i=1
    while i < 10:
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n'+str(i)+b'\r\n')
        i+=1

def get_frame():
    ramp_frames=100

    camera=cv2.VideoCapture('IMG_2649.MOV')

    i=1
    while True:
        retval, im = camera.read()
        imgencode=cv2.imencode('.jpg',im)[1]
        stringData=imgencode.tostring()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
            b'Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n'+stringData+b'\r\n')
        i+=1

    del(camera)

@app.route('/calc')
def calc():
     return Response(get_frame(),mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', debug=True, threaded=True)
```

HTML Code

```
   <html>
      <head>
        <title>Video Streaming Demonstration</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Video Streaming Demonstration</h1>
        <img src="{{ url_for('calc') }}">
        <!-- <h1>{{ url_for('calc') }}</h1> -->
      </body>
    </html>
```